# picking out an element from a nodelist

Tags: javascript, arrays, nodelist

I've just started to learn some basics of javascript so I'm still confused about several concepts.

I'm hoping some of you can kindly help me with this simple question about nodelist and everything.

I was trying to write code to make a program similar to 'wordle' and I got curious how the code below work well.

```
    <input class="input">
    <input class="input">
    <input class="input">
    <input class="input">
    <input class="input">
    <button>submit</button>

    <script>
        let answer = 'abcde';
        document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
           var input = document.querySelectorAll('.input');

            for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
              if (input[i].value == answer[i]) {
                input[i].style.background = 'green';
            } else if (answer.includes(input[i].value)) {
                input[i].style.background = 'yellow';
            } else {
                input[i].style.backgrouond = 'lightgrey';
            }
    </script>
```

I thought that `querySelectorAll('.input')` would return a nodelist composed of 5 input elements.

So I was going to put a code like `input[0][0]` to access the first character of the first string of the list, but without an extra `[0]` it worked fine.

That's what confuses me now.

And plus, can anyone tell me what `.value` does?

what is this property (or method maybe..?) doing here?

Comment: You need to first access the `value` of the input. Value is an [attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attributes) of the input element.

Comment: `backgrouond` is misspelled. `value` is a property (not an attribute in this context); see [`HTMLInputElement.prototype.value`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#value).

Comment: for loop does not have closing brace, anonymous function in the click listener does not have closing brace. the addeventlistener does not have closing brace

Answer (score 0):

To get the first character of the first input value, you need to use the following:

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input');
const firstInputValue = inputs[0].value;
const firstCharacter = firstInputValue[0];
```

After getting all the elements with class "input", you get the value of the first element in the NodeList and then take the first character of that input.

The value property is used to get or set the input value of the input field. Take a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp) for more information.